# Program work in Windows not in mac

Tags: java, macos, filesystems

```
File updateDirectory = new File("NewFolder");
        if (updateDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            if (updateDirectory.list().length > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, updateDirectory.list().length);}}}
```

In windows it shows 1 and in mac it shows 2 when placing a file in "NewFolder".
How can I fix this for both.
Thanks

Comment: Do you know what `list()` method does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Mac you might have created a [".DS_Store"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) file when placing the file in the folder. Files starting with a "." are hidden on a Mac, and therefore you can't see it in the Finder.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might either want to ignore all ".DS_Store" files or all files starting with a ".".

Here is how you ignore these files:

```java
    updateDirectory.list(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.startsWith(".");
        }
    });
```

To find out, you can print out the array you get from  the `list()` method.

Please note, that on Windows, files starting with "." are *not* hidden, so you might confuse your users. I recommend to implement the filter with care - maybe even with a operating system specific variant.